# update action deleting and creating a new record in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on two models with a one to one relationship; the update method is deleting the record it's suppose to update and creating a new one.

**The two models - user.rb and profile.rb**

USER.RB

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :remember_token

    before_save {self.email = email.downcase }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                         format:{with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, 
                         uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

   has_secure_password
   validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

    has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

end
```

PROFILE.RB

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :street, :city, :state, :zipcode, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Their controllers**

USER CONTROLLER

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy

  def new
   @user = User.new
   @profile = @user.build_profile
  end

  def create
   @user = User.new(user_params)
   if @user.save
    log_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Mini Olympics"
    redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user, @profile)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
 end

 def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def edit
   # Commented out the code, as its redundant due to the line 'before_action :correct_user'
   # @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def update
   # Commented out  first line of the code, as its redundant due to the line 'before_action :correct_user'
   # @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "profile updated"
    #redirect_to @user
    redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user, @profile)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
 end

 def index
   @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
 end

 def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "User deleted"
  redirect_to users_url
 end

 private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, profile_attributes: [:name, 
        :street, :city, :state, :zipcode] )
    end

   # Before filters

   # Confirms a logged-in user.
   def logged_in_user
     unless logged_in?
       store_location
       flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
      redirect_to login_url
     end
   end

   # Confirms the correct user.
   def correct_user
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)   # '@user == current_user' = 'current_user?(@user)'
   end

   # Confirms an admin user. 
   def admin_user
     redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
   end
 end
```

PROFILE CONTROLLER

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    @profile = User.find(params[:user_id]).profile
  end

  def show
    @profile = User.find(params[:user_id]).profile 
  end

  def update
     @profile = User.find(params[:user_id]).profile 
     if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
      flash[:success] = "profile updated"
      redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user, @profile)
     else
       render 'edit'
     end
  end

  private

    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:id, :name, :street, :city, :state, :zipcode)
    end

 end
```

**Profile edit form**

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit Profile") %>
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
   <%= form_for [:user, @profile] do |f| %>
     <%= render 'fields', f: f %>
     <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
   <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

APP/VIEWS/PROFILES/_FIELDS.HTML.ERB

```
 <%= f.label :name %>
 <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

 <%= f.label :street %>
 <%= f.text_field :street, class: 'form-control' %>

 <%= f.label :city %>
 <%= f.text_field :city, class: 'form-control' %>

 <%= f.label :state %>
 <%= f.text_field :state, class: 'form-control' %>

 <%= f.label :zipcode %>
 <%= f.text_field :zipcode, class: 'form-control' %>
```

**Server log**

```
 Started GET "/users/1/profile/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-11 20:27:27 -0400
 Processing by ProfilesController#edit as HTML
 Parameters: {"user_id"=>"1"}
 User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
 Profile Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `profiles`.* FROM `profiles`  WHERE profiles`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
 Rendered profiles/_fields.html.erb (9.0ms)
 Rendered profiles/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (30.0ms)
 Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
 User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (15.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1896ms (Views: 1874.9ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)

Started PATCH "/users/104/profile" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-11 20:27:34 -0400
Processing by ProfilesController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√","authenticity_token"=>"h7gQEkz8JV/u4zT2qX7ivxRz9FLRUi4K42h55mokP/0=", "profile"=>{"name"=>"Example Test", "street"=>"75 Barracks Rd", "city"=>"Water", "state"=>"AW", "zipcode"=>"23455"}, "commit"=>"Save changes","user_id"=>"104"}
User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 104 LIMIT 1
Completed 404 Not Found in 47ms

  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=104):
  app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:19:in `update'
```

How did 1 become 104; /users/1/profile/edit  to /users/104/profile?

when i update user i.e /users/1/edit, i get

```
 Started GET "/users/1/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-11 19:16:54 -0400
 Processing by UsersController#edit as HTML
   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
 User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
 User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
 Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (57.4ms)
 Profile Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  `profiles`.* FROM `profiles`  WHERE `profiles`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
 Rendered users/_fields.html.erb (835.0ms)
 Rendered users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (1193.9ms)
 Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
 Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (90.4ms)
 Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (265.6ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 3979ms (Views: 3962.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)

 Started PATCH "/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-11 19:17:11 -0400
 Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
 Parameters:{"utf8"=>"√","authenticity_token"=>"h7gQEkz8JV/u4zT2qX7ivxRz9FLRUi4K42h55mokP/0=", "user"=>{"profile_attributes"=>{"name"=>"Example Test", "id"=>"103", "street"=>"75 Barracks Rd", "city"=>"Water", "state"=>"AW", "zipcode"=>"23455"}, "email"=>"example@test.org", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Save changes", "id"=>"1"}
   User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   Unpermitted parameters: id  (14.0ms)  BEGIN
   Profile Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  `profiles`.* FROM `profiles`  WHERE `profiles`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   SQL (212.4ms)  DELETE FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`id` = 103
   User Exists (143.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users`  WHERE (`users`.`email` = 'example@test.org' AND `users`.`id` != 1) LIMIT 1
   SQL (53.0ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `password_digest` =$2a$10$1KoyfbAwjKYVlwCsbB4WpObW5D.giibIU3pK5hRYW4.iwc11ZEAVS', `updated_at` = '2015-08-11 23:17:14' WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
  SQL (31.0ms)  INSERT INTO `profiles` (`city`, `created_at`, `name`, state`, `street`, `updated_at`, `user_id`, `zipcode`) VALUES ('Water', '2015-08-11 23:17:15', 'Example Test', 'AW', '75 Barracks Rd', '2015-08-11 23:17:15', 1, '23455')   (94.1ms)  COMMIT
  Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/1/profile
  Completed 302 Found in 4234ms (ActiveRecord: 551.7ms)


  Started GET "/users/1/profile" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-11 19:17:15 -0400
  Processing by ProfilesController#show as HTML
   Parameters: {"user_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Profile Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `profiles`.* FROM `profiles`  WHERE `profiles`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered profiles/show.html.erb within layouts/application (9.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (9.0ms)
   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
   Completed 200 OK in 1917ms (Views: 1898.3ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
```

I am at a loss at whats triggering the `Delete` command, any help is appreciated..

ROUTES FOLDER

Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
 root             'static_pages#home'

 get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
 get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
 get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'

 get  'signup' => 'users#new'

 get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
 post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
 delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

 resources :users do
   resource :profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update ]
 end
end
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you have to also set the `id` in your `profile_attributes` on `user_params`

Comment: Isn't `104` the `profile` id?

Comment: yes, the profile id changes from 1 to 104

Comment: Have you tried adding the `id` in your list of permitted params for users?

Comment: Thanks @Gerep, it worked though it redirected to `/users/1/profile.1`. I don't understand the `.1`.

Comment: Edit your question adding your routes file please.

Comment: @Gerep, i added routes file.

Comment: Please try changing this like `redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user, @profile)` to this `redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user, @profile.id)`

Comment: @Gerep, sorry this took a while but that didn't work. I have made it a separate question in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994703/what-does-1-mean-in-users-1-profile-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `id` on your list of permitted attributes on `UsersController`:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, profile_attributes: [:id, :name, 
    :street, :city, :state, :zipcode] )
end
```